# Unable to parse JSON response object Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, node.js, post, alamofire

I am making a post request and get back a JSON response in the form of `[Object object]`. I tried various ways to parse this JSON but wasn't able to. Whenever I try, I get an error saying `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x10f3dc4a0) to 'NSData'`

On the backend side, I have a NodeJS server that replies with `res.send`. Do I need to convert this data to something else or is there a way I can parse this JSON Data and get the Dictionary object that I am originally supposed to get. I'm using Swift 3 with Alamofire 4.0.

How can I solve this issue?

This is my request code in iOS

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)


        let data_temp = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.result.value! as! Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

            print(data_temp)
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Use `res.json()` to send `json` from `node.js`

Comment: But that does not send it as json. Right?